# Identify keypress action in vim

Tags: vim

I'm transitioning to vim from another vi-like editor. I keep trying to use my old key combinations but of course vim has different mappings. How can I find out what function is mapped to the key combination I pushed? For example, I might push <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> and something happens, but I don't understand what it is, and want to learn about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do this:

```
:help ^o
```

Where ^o is pressing <kbd>CTRL-o</kbd>

Comment: Typing out `:help <C-o>` also works, and that format will fork for any command, just type `:help <key sequence>`

Comment: `:help index` is also good. It lists all the keys/commands and their functions.

Comment: I would add that it's very important to read through the page that comes up when you just type ":help" since it introduces the user to the conventions and notations of the actual help documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the mapping and its source via the different map commands. For example: `:verbose map <C-K>*` could output something like this:

```
v  <C-K>       * :m-2<CR>gv=gv
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
n  <C-K>       * :m-2<CR>==
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

If you have some time to kill have a look at the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29) on the topic of key mappings. Their tutorial covers all you need.

If you've got Ruby on your machine I can highly recommend the [vimdb gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/vimdb).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [vimdb](https://github.com/cldwalker/vimdb) could be something for you. From the project website:

> Increase the speed and amount of vim knowledge at your fingertips with precise searching of vim's items: keys (keybindings), options and commands. vimdb is aware of vim's default items, ones in your vimrc and ones in plugins